# Is there a power bank that would work properly on MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019)?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

Is there a power bank that would work properly on MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019) ?

Answer (score 2):

The MacBook will charge from anything that connects to a USB-C cable.

The Apple Charger for the 15" MacBook Pro charges with 87 Watts. Anything lower will also work, but will charge slower. I'd look for something with a 60 Watt or at very least 45 Watt output. I think anything below that would be painfully slow.